# Turn off inserting of space before opening brace of blocks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, code-formatting

How do I turn off the inserting of a space before the opening brace of blocks.

[image: Gif]

It's a minor thing, but it's annoying that I cannot find an option for this.  It's available in the C/C++ options, but not for C#.

Comment: Not sure in VS itself, but ReSharper does have [the option to do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDRHi.png).  I don't think such a small thing is worth justifying the expense though :)

Comment: I thought it automatically dropped the brace to a newline?  Maybe I've been using ReSharper too long!

Comment: That's how C# should be styled, why would you want to turn that off? You are not programming in C/C++, not the same language, not the same styling rules.

Comment: @Tom that is the default (to move to new line) VS behavior when you select C# as development style

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The default is to put a space or newline?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto because that's not how C# *should* be styled, it's just a styling preference. One that can be controlled by editor settings, just like many others. There is no default. In fact, VS 2017 Update 3 allows you to skip the newline

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Of course there are defaults, what are you talking about? Every single preference in VS comes with a default, just like any program that has preferences the user can change. And that's not even close to new in VS 2017, even VS2013 allows you to do that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto we are talking about code style. And what may appear as the default or most usual to you, is downright weird to others. Using `this` for fields? Whatever for, just use a `_`. What do you mean StyleCop, the community does it this way. What do you mean not your community ?

Comment: To the OP: do you mind showing where you see the option in the C/C++ section? VS2013 Ultimate U5 does not have that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the question is about VS 2017, which does have such options

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto "That's how C# should be styled" - No, "should" is not correct.  It's a recommendation.  No style should be forced.  There are times when it's recommended to use a more "standard" style to keep code readable and easier to maintain.  But in my case, I am a solo dev that is not putting this out in the public domain, so my style can be whatever it likes.  The fact that there is no option to simply remove a space, is a little annoying, regardless if it's the "correct" style to be using or not.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> Spacing.  It's under "Spacing for braces".  The option is called "Insert space before opening brace of blocks".

Comment: This is the first time I see someone wanting to remove that space, so that's most likely why you don't see the option (too little people asking for it). Have you tried to search the UserVoice community for such a request?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you'll have to tell Mars Torgersen that you don't like Visual Studio 2017. What is being discussed here is changes that have been added to the latest VS version and more are comming

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It's not a big issue to be honest, I can simply remove it myself.  I couldn't workout why there was no option for it.  I'm new to VS, so am not used to having something forced on me like that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I use VS2017 most of the time, I'm on VS2013 right now due to client requirements though.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto as for why it isn't already available - says who? People have been using Resharper for this for over a decade. It *is* available because it is in demand. Visual Studio just **didn't** have a good enough formatter until 2015. Now, with Roslyn this is possible and Microsoft is adding this functionality as Roslyn addins and features

Comment: @JacketPotatoeFan even if you do remove them by hand, whenever the format document event is triggered, the space will be reinserted.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto then I suggest you check again, and watch [The Future of C#](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/B8104) from Build. Expect more changes like this

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto What triggers the format event?  I've yet to have that happen, and as far as I know I haven't disabled any auto format feature.

Comment: @JacketPotatoeFan CTRL+K, CTRL+D will trigger it, as well other events. You can *disable* automatic formatting entirely, which will prevent it doing what you are seeing, but this will also prevent *all* automatic formatting from taking place.

Comment: Thanks for asking this! That space annoys me a lot and even worse is the inability to turn it off - coders who believe there is a "one true way" to code should rethink their stance. Hope a solution will appear in the near future... cheers to a free thinker by the way! :)